# SelectionChane is called but ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count = 0 in Outlook VSTO AddIn:

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I try to get the currently selected AppointmentItem. For this, I handle the SelectionChange Event of the ActiveExplorer. 
SelectionChange is called often but when I try to get the Selection the count = 0. Is this a known bug of Outlook? You can check this for yourself with:

[...]

```
currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(Selection_Change);
```

[...]
then handle the events here:

```
private void Selection_Change()
{
    log.Info("currently selected: "+this.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count);
}
```

Run your addon open the calendar or the inbox. I/you will get a lot of "currently selected: 0"

But in the documentation, it says apart from FileFolders Outlook automatically selects the first item in the current view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/bb645132(v%3Doffice.14) Therefore Selection.Count shouldn't be 0???

Any advice on this

Comment: Where did you get an instance of the Explorer class? Which Outlook version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The [Selection.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Selection.Count) property returns an integer that indicates the number of items or conversation headers in the selection. It works like a charm on my machine. Most probably something is wrong with your code - you have got multiple explorer windows opened and get the selection object from non-active one and etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with `Selection.Count == 0`. Switch to the Calendar folder in the Calendar view and click a time slot with no appointment - Selection.Count will be 0.